Flink Missing resources
I'm working with Flink 1.18.1, one of the pipelines has some problems and at some point for unknown reasons TaskManager restarts and has trouble initializing:

In TaskManager theres only Java-level error:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc77a1944bf, pid=1, tid=391

In JobManager i can see logs like this:
2024-11-12 15:27:13.001 
2024-11-12 14:27:13,000 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.DefaultSlotStatusSyncer [] - Starting allocation of slot 68f4b9a6f8243289ac95d2f32b7ec1cf from xx.xx.0.219:xxx-dd39bc for job f2e512b96b238a413633456f42b7ef21with resource profile ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1, taskHeapMemory=2.049gb (2199912448 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=11.725gb (12589622671 bytes), networkMemory=2.726gb (2927204977 bytes)}.
2024-11-12 15:27:13.005 
2024-11-12 14:27:13,005 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer             [] - Committing checkpoint/app-name/rocksDBstorage/949294afcef3dfa56f0a6e2c7e4436f7/chk-1812/_metadata with MPU ID NWQyYTMxOGEtYzM1OS00MzMzLTkxYTEtZDdlNjQ3ZjgyNzI3LjI3N2Y0M2UzLTExMjMtNDI3Ny1hYWUzLWM2OTQ2NmVkNDA4NHgxNzMxNDIxNjMyOTU1MDk4MjQ5
2024-11-12 15:27:13.018 
2024-11-12 14:27:13,018 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.DefaultSlotStatusSyncer [] - Freeing slot 68f4b9a6f8243289ac95d2f32b7ec1cf.
2024-11-12 15:27:13.019 
2024-11-12 14:27:13,019 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Disconnect TaskExecutor xx.xx.0.219:xxx-dd39bc because: TaskExecutor pekko.tcp://flink@xx.xx.0.219:xxx/user/rpc/taskmanager_0 has no more allocated slots for job f2e512b96b238a413633456f42b7ef21.
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
2024-11-12 14:27:13,079 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.FineGrainedSlotManager [] - Matching resource requirements against available resources.
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
Missing resources:

2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
     Job f2e512b96b238a413633456f42b7ef21
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        ResourceRequirement{resourceProfile=ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}, numberOfRequiredSlots=1}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
Current resources:
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
    TaskManager xx.xx.0.219:xxx-b6ea2e
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Available: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=0, taskHeapMemory=0 bytes, taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=0 bytes, networkMemory=0 bytes}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Total:     ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1, taskHeapMemory=2.049gb (2199912448 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=11.725gb (12589622671 bytes), networkMemory=2.726gb (2927204977 bytes)}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
    TaskManager xx.xx.0.219:xxx-bbb4fa
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Available: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=0, taskHeapMemory=0 bytes, taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=0 bytes, networkMemory=0 bytes}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Total:     ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1, taskHeapMemory=2.049gb (2199912448 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=11.725gb (12589622671 bytes), networkMemory=2.726gb (2927204977 bytes)}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
    TaskManager xx.xx.0.219:xxx-a1345b
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Available: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=0, taskHeapMemory=0 bytes, taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=0 bytes, networkMemory=0 bytes}
2024-11-12 15:27:13.080 
        Total:     ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1, taskHeapMemory=2.049gb (2199912448 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=11.725gb (12589622671 bytes), networkMemory=2.726gb (2927204977 bytes)}

I didn't find any information on how to understand the "Missing Resources" log. It's not marked as Error or anything like that.
Should I interpret this log as a problem with insufficient resources for this pipeline, and the cause of problem with it or is this normal behavior of the Flink JobManager and should I look elsewhere for the cause of the pipeline not working?

The cause of the SIGSEGV (0xb) error needs to be resolved, as that's definitely not normal. I'd guess it's related to RocksDB. If that's what you're using for state, what happens if you change the state backend to be hashmap?

@kkrugler i create new question with more logs for this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79188363/flink-classloader-cannot-be-null-kryo

I would close this issue, since it's been superseded by the new question.
